# The known whereabouts of Littlefinger

Tags: game-of-thrones, a-song-of-ice-and-fire

These spoilers are from season 4 episodes 2–5.

> After the murder of Joffrey, Petyr Baylesh goes to and stays at
>  the Vale. Does he have a cover story for his absence from King’s
>  Landing? Why isn’t anybody suspicious that he went missing the day of
>  the assassination? As far as the Small Council & friends are concerned
>  where do they think Littlefinger is?

Comment: I don't remember the exact quotes from books but according to [wiki](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Petyr_Baelish#A_Storm_of_Swords) he was sent to Vale (so he had an alibi) but he stayed around hidden. **EDIT** ups - that's about the series so it might not apply.

Comment: @MaciejPiechotka I don’t mind answers from the books, thank you

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Littlefinger departs King's Landing for the Vale in the season 3 episode [The Climb](http://gameofthrones.wikia.com/wiki/The_Climb), with the expectations of those in King's Landing that he is going to try and marry Lysa Arryn and ally the Vale with the Crown.

No one explicitly states it, but given that such a task could take awhile, no one seems to miss him or think twice about him not being there at Joffrey's wedding.

Anyway, going back to Season 3 (and tying into this season) this is why:

> At the end of the episode (IIRC), Littlefinger declares "The climb is all there is." in direct reference to his climb in power, and with the implication that he is still climbing even further.

Answer (score 4):

**He leaves quite some time *before* Joffrey dies and is assumed to have nothing to do with it.**

Part of his plan includes him being sent to the Vale in order to garner support for Kings Landing from House Arryn by marrying Lysa.

Note: After The Battle of the Blackwater Littlefinger also receives control of Harrenhal. 
It is mentioned by others that he is taking his time in the Vale, because he is in no rush to take command Harrenhal.

Littlefinger does have a plan, and his future contribution to the plot will likely be very significant.

As commented by Varys to Illyrio Mopatis, "Littlefinger... the gods only know what game Littlefinger is playing."